# SQL: Sort by Nearest comma-separated dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with dates stored in comma separated like below

```
9/30/2013,9/17/2013,10/16/2013,
5/27/2013, 9/30/2013,
09/24/2013,09/27/2013,
09/13/2013,11/18/2013,
09/11/2013,09/13/2013,
12/27/2013,12/20/2013,
12/27/2013,12/20/2013,12/13/2013,12/6/2013,11/29/2013,
10/3/2013,10/10/2013,10/17/2013,10/24/2013,10/31/2013,
10/31/2013,10/24/2013,10/17/2013,10/10/2013,10/3/2013,
```

Now my task is sort the records with nearest first, past dates can be ignored. Need to compare all dates in a row with current date, please suggest how can I achieve this

Thanks in advance.

Edited

I'm excepting:

```
9/30/2013,9/17/2013,10/16/2013, as 10/16/2013 is nearest of all
10/3/2013,10/10/2013,10/17/2013,10/24/2013,10/31/2013, as 10/17/2013 next nearest
10/31/2013,10/24/2013,10/17/2013,10/10/2013,10/3/2013,
12/27/2013,12/20/2013,12/13/2013,12/6/2013,11/29/2013,
12/27/2013,12/20/2013,
```

Comment: Please provide expected output for your data sample.

Comment: Also please provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: Why, why, why are you storing data like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a udf to convert your string to a table of dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ConvertCSVStringToDateTable] 
(
    @CSVString varchar(max)
)
RETURNS 
@DateTable TABLE 
(
    [Date] DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ListSize BIGINT
    DECLARE @FoundIndex BIGINT
    DECLARE @Date INT
    DECLARE @DateString VARCHAR(10)

    SET @ListSize = LEN(@CSVString)

    WHILE(@ListSize > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @CSVString)

        IF(@FoundIndex = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @DateString = @CSVString
            SET @CSVString = ''
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @DateString = SUBSTRING(@CSVString, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)
            SET @CSVString = SUBSTRING(@CSVString, @FoundIndex + 1, @ListSize) 
        END

        IF(ISDATE(@DateString) = 1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT @DateTable([Date]) VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, @DateString))
        END

        SET @ListSize = LEN(@CSVString)
    END
    RETURN 
END
```

From that you should be able to do a select and filter using a `WHERE` clause or order using an `ORDER BY` clause